# How to dynamically load image into picturebox in fast report?

Tags: fastreport

I have a table in Sql that has 2 columns containing header and address of images that related to that header like below:
Header      address

```
194003      ~/viewerImages/1903-01-1-5-0-6-00143.jpg
194003      ~/viewerImages/1903-01-1-5-0-6-00161.jpg
194003      ~/viewerImages/1903-01-1-5-0-6-00190.jpg
194012      ~/viewerImages/1903-01-1-5-0-6-00143.jpg
194012      ~/viewerImages/1903-01-1-5-0-7-00141.jpg
194012      ~/viewerImages/1903-01-1-5-0-7-00160.jpg
194015      ~/viewerImages/1903-01-1-5-0-7-00180.jpg
194015      ~/viewerImages/1903-01-1-5-0-8-00159.jpg
194015      ~/viewerImages/1903-01-1-5-0-8-00184.jpg
```

I want to load these images dynamically in fastreport for each header.
what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create an objet with some properties that are the images to load (image1, image2, image3). You also add more properties with the data that you want to print in the report. 
Then, you can load the information in the object dinamically and after send the object to the report, so Fast Reports will print the information you are loading in the object. In this way you can do wharever you want dinamically.
For image properties, you can use Image or byte[] type.

To create the report:

```
var report = new Report();
report.Load(Constants.Paths.ReportFolder + "Return.frx");

report.RegisterData(myObject, "Name");
report.Design(); // if you want to open the designer before to print
report.Show();
```

Note: The object to register must be a collection of objects. In this case myObject would be a List. If you want to register a single object, you can do it in this way:

report.RegisterData(new List{ myObject }), "Name");

In the designer you can access all the properties.